# Animation flashing with fixed header, how to stop?

Tags: jquery, menu, scroll

I have a fixed header and wanted to make a fade animation on the logo, but when i scroll it flashes, I have seen .stop() and .finish()at the Jquery documentation, but dont know how to implement it in the scroll function.

```
Here is the fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n25dw0qq/8/

(sorry for my bad english).

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the fade functions run every single time that `scroll` is triggered, of course this is what will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time you scroll the animation gets triggered. Make sure you trigger the animation only once.

An easy way to do this, is adding a variable to keep track of the animation state.

```
var wasAnimated = false;

if (!wasAnimated) {
   $('#myimage').fadeOut('fast', function() {
       // Do something else
   });
   wasAnimated = true;
}
```

I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n25dw0qq/9/). Check it out.

A better solution would be changing your application logic to trigger the animation only at a certain window offset position. For example at Y = 37. Don't use `$(this).scrollTop() > 0` for this purpose.